# Vue - Recursively inserting <div>

Tags: html, vue.js, recursion, syntax, vue-component

I'm trying to recursively insert a div element that contains a button as follows:

```
<div v-for="column in 25" :key="column.id" class="columna">
  <div v-for="row in 10" :key="row.id" class="recuadro">
    {{ row == 1 ? 'PAXXX' : `<div class="selector"><button onclick="colorCell()" /></div>` }}
  </div>
</div>
```

Basically it inserts row element name first and then fulfills the row with a selectable div that has an invisible button.

I'm getting syntax error in `<div class="selector"><button onclick="colorCell()" /></div>`:

Missing ` (placed right under <div...)

Any suggest will be appreciated

Comment: BTW, you are not doing recursion here. This is iteration. See [What's the difference between recursion and iteration?](https://www.educative.io/edpresso/whats-the-difference-between-recursion-and-iteration).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code from the question above:

```
{{ row == 1
  ? 'PAXXX'
  : `<div class="selector"><button onclick="colorCell()" /></div>`
}}
```

Is not valid, as you can place only text (not HTML) inside double mustaches.

Using `v-if` and `v-else` works as intended and avoids the syntax error:

```html
  <div v-for="column in 25" :key="column.id" class="columna">
    <div v-for="row in 10" :key="row.id" class="recuadro">
      <span v-if="row == 1">PAXXX</span>
      <div v-else class="selector"><button onclick="colorCell()" /></div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Or you can use the `v-html` attribute to tell vue to treat the contents as raw HTML.

```html
<div v-for="column in 25" :key="column.id" class="columna">
  <div v-for="row in 10" :key="row.id" class="recuadro"
    v-html="row == 1 ? 'PAXXX' : `<div class='selector'><button onclick='colorCell()' /></div>`"
  >
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your insight. Is it an acceptable practice to use v-for AND v-if? While searching for a solution to this I've read it is not.

Comment: @MatiasGSP I'm not aware of a restriction preventing the use of `v-if` within a `v-for` loop. You may also consider the `v-html` alternative, which is simpler. See my updated answer.

Comment: I'm really thankful for your complete answer. I'm marking your response as the correct solution!

Comment: @MatiasGSP Using `v-for` and `v-if` *on the same element* should be avoided, according to the [Vue Style Guide](https://vuejs.org/v2/style-guide/#Avoid-v-if-with-v-for-essential). Using `v-if` on an element inside a `v-for` loop appears to be okay.